# setState not working as expected in react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I am updating the with setState hook, value is not getting updated.
As per my knowledge this setState call is async. How to solve this issue?

```
export default function ResultItem({result:{ name, result_type, entry, unit, min_val, max_val, in_spec}, handleEntryChange}){
const [inSpec, setInSpec] = useState(in_spec)
const [result, setResult] = useState(entry);

console.log(handleEntryChange)
return(
    <Fragment>

        <td>{name}</td>
        <td>{result_type}</td>
        <td>{}</td>
        <td>
            <input
                name={name} 
                type={result_type === 'numeric' ? "number" : "text"}
                value={result || ''}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    let val = parseInt(e.target.value)
                    setResult(val)
                    if(val >= min_val && val <= max_val){
                        setInSpec(true);
                    }else{
                        setInSpec(false);
                    }
                    console.log(result, inSpec, val)
                    handleEntryChange({[name]: val, [name]: inSpec});
                }}
            />
        </td>
        <td>{unit}</td>
        <td>{inSpec? 'YES': 'NO'}{console.log(in_spec)}</td>
    </Fragment>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to make a custom Input. In general, you need to be careful of how this input is controlled ? On your interface, you have `entry` (which might be the initial value) but internally you have `result`.

Both are actually the `value` in Input context, but they normally are either controlled from external (on the interface) or tracked internally, but not both.

Just imaging if `entry` is changed, what could be `result` ?

The right way is the following

```
  const Input = ({ value, onChange }) => {
    // no internal state here
    return (
       <input value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    )
  }
```

This is a pure pass through model with both `value` and `onChange` driven by external.

Now you might ask how do I change the look and feel of my custom Input.

You can now write wrapper for `onChange` to inject your own implementation.

```
  const onValueChange = e => {
    // e.target.value
    // do your own handling and then
    // if need call onChange(e) to handle external
  }

  <input onChange={onValueChange} />
```

I'll skip the UI change for `input` here, since your example is already there.

The last comment here, the controlled input does not have storage. So in order to use your input, you need to have a state defined from external.

```
  const [result, setResult] = useState(0)
  return (
    <YourInput value={result} />
  )
```

The take home message here is WHO should manage the storage (memory), this might be the #1 fixture to put into place before designing any component.

Comment: 1. The 'entry' value will not change over the lifecycle of this component.    2. I am not trying to create any custom input field. I want to update some states based on the input value and send it to parent component.